# Is it used in positive or negative sense "jemandem den Kopf waschen"

Tags: idiom

I wonder if this idiom has a positive meaning, It seems to me somehow it means "to cause one's mind to be changed" regardless of caring he does a good thing or not.Could you please explain when do you use it?

> jemandem den Kopf waschen

Comment: Jemandem den Kopf waschen ist positiv, jmd. nicht den Kopf waschen ist negativ. Alles andere ist subjektiv und keine Frage der Sprache.

Comment: @user unknown, bei konstruktiver Kritik ist es nicht eindeutig positiv oder negativ,  aber "jemandem den Kopf zu waschen" würde ich niemals positiv verstehen. Ich würde es gleichzusetzen mit "jemanden zurecht stauchen" oder "jemanden die Leviten lesen". Auch wenn die Konsequenzen vielleicht schlussendlich positiv für denjenigen sind,  ist der Akt selbst doch eindeutig negativ.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, there's almost never a positive connotation with that. 
It is actually closer to "to give someone a piece of someone's mind" than simply "to cause one's mind to be changed". You can also assume that the guy who "washes the other guy's head" has some sort of authority over him, and that the "washing" is going to contain quite a bit of strong language.

Comment: Ob jemand einem anderen den Kopf wäscht oder nicht, das kann man bewerten wie man will. Man muss es auch nicht bewerten und kann es dennoch sagen. Selbst derjenige, dem der Kopf gewaschen wird, kann das ganze positiv bewerten, und zwar weil er Einsicht in die Notwendigkeit erlangt. Nur liegt im Satz der Fokus ja gar nicht auf dem, dem der Kopf gewaschen wird.

Comment: Ich tu mir ein bisschen schwer, mir jemanden-gesunden Geisteszustand vorausgesetzt - vorzustellen,  der den Augenblick des Kopfwaschens genießt bzw positiv betrachtet -ob er nachher zu der Erkenntnis gelangt, dass ihm das gut getan hat, steht ja auf einem anderen Blatt.

Comment: Die Phrase ist aber "jemandem den Kopf waschen", nicht "von jemandem den Kopf gewaschen bekommen". Außerdem geht es nicht darum, ob jemand das genießt, sondern wie man die Aktion im Kontext bewertet. Vielleicht hat ein Flugschüler einen dummen Fehler gemacht, der im Ernstfall einen Flugzeugabsturz bedeutet hätte, und der Schüler freut sich letztlich, dass er es dank der heftigen Kritik verstanden und verinnerlicht hat und ist kein weinerlicher Egozentriker, der nur sein eigenes Wohlfühlen im Auge hat.

Answer (score 5):

*Jemandem den Kopf waschen* when used figuratively means ‘to tell someone off’, ‘to reprimand someone’. Consequently, the meaning is rather negative.

> Er kam fast eine Stunde zu spät. Da habe ich ihm aber erst einmal den Kopf gewaschen.

Comment: So he's angry at you,and that's why he is late, right?

Comment: No; the speaker is angry at him because he is late.

Comment: In your example "da" means "because" or "there" or "daher"? I didn't know "da" can be used in a result sentence. We've learnt "da" shows a reason.

Comment: @user1474062 *da* is indeed used as *weil*, but first, not only, and secondly, if in that meaning, the verb should be at the end.

Comment: Ob jemand einem anderen den Kopf wäscht oder nicht, das kann man bewerten wie man will. Man muss es auch nicht bewerten und kann es dennoch sagen. Selbst derjenige, dem der Kopf gewaschen wird, kann das ganze positiv bewerten, und zwar weil er Einsicht in die Notwendigkeit erlangt. Nur liegt im Satz der Fokus ja gar nicht auf dem, dem der Kopf gewaschen wird.